# Angular matSort not working on Date column by desc

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Trying to sort the material table with date column , date format is 'MM/DD/YYYY ,h:mm A' , order of date is not by latest date and time. Anything which i missed from the below stackblitz code.

https://angular-matsordesc.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you upload the code to https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matsordesc , here is the code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the sort is sorting the date as type `string` instead of type `date`.

It works for me changing the `ngAfterViewInit` for this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'date': {
          let newDate = new Date(item.date);
          return newDate;
        }
        default: {
          return item[property];
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

What we are doing here it's when the sort executes, in the case of the date we convert the `item.date` from string to date. Then the sort executes the property date as a type `date`.

Here I add a screenshot of https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matsordesc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts where is working:

[image]

Comment: Still the same issue ,the order sort is not by today's date.and the item.date is undefined

Comment: That is strange. I tested in stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matsordesc  and it works for me. Are you importing ```MatTableModule``` and ```MatTableModule``` in the module where has been defined your component?

Comment: i just see it again here is the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matsordesc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have just try it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matsordesc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts and it's working fine. I upload a Screenshot to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file,

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

this.sort.sort({
id: 'columnname',
start: 'asc',
disableClear: false
})

case 'columnname': return ((a[sort.active] ? new Date(a[sort.active]).getTime() : 1) < (b[sort.active] ? new Date(b[sort.active]).getTime() : 1) ? 1 : -1) * (isAsc ? -1 : 1);

German Quinteros, your solution works fine.This ia another solution for the same issue. But in both cases, when there is ngIf* in a <mat-cell then there will be some empty values in between sorted values of the column.